# selenium web scraping in c#

Tags: c#, selenium

I am doing web scraping by using selenium dll's.But i face the problem when scrape the list of records. If I use the debugger it extract all the records, but if disable debugger and run the application it sometime display less records or sometime display no record.I want to know is there is any way to know that yet the page is fully loaded or not.

> driver.FindElementsByClassName("search-result-gridview-item").ToList()

vary the record count.

```
                            driver.FindElementsByClassName("search-result-gridview-item").ToList().ForEach(x =>
                            {
                                objUPCProcess = new UPCProcessingModel();
                                try
                                {
                                    objUPCProcess.Description = x.FindElement(By.ClassName("prod-ProductTitle")).Text;
                                    objUPCProcess.Price = x.FindElement(By.ClassName("Price")).Text;
                                    listOfProductDetails.Add(objUPCProcess);
                                    if (i == 0)
                                    {
                                        log.Item = objUPCProcess.Description;
                                        i++;
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (OpenQA.Selenium.NoSuchElementException ex)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        objUPCProcess.Description = x.FindElement(By.ClassName("prod-ProductTitle")).Text;
                                        objUPCProcess.Price = ex.Message;
                                        listOfProductDetails.Add(objUPCProcess);
                                    }
                                    catch
                                    {
                                        try
                                        {
                                            objUPCProcess.Price = x.FindElement(By.ClassName("Price")).Text;
                                            objUPCProcess.Description = ex.Message;
                                            listOfProductDetails.Add(objUPCProcess);
                                        }
                                        catch
                                        {
                                            objUPCProcess.Description = ex.Message;
                                            objUPCProcess.Price = ex.Message;
                                            log.Message = ex.Message;
                                            listOfProductDetails.Add(objUPCProcess);
                                            log.Status = "Error";
                                        }

                                    }


                                }
                            });
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at this case, I'm pretty sure this is caused by a synchronization issue (webdriver and page work at a different speed) with AJAX requests that actually populate the records. That's why

> if disable debugger and run the application it sometime display less records or sometime display no record

I also don't see any [explicit waits](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/c-sharp/advance-explicit-webdriver-waits-in-c/) in your code. But you can implement a helper `Utils` method that will check

> that yet the page is fully loaded or not

I've used the `IScriptExecutor` like so:

```
public void WaitSecondsForNewPageToLoad(int maxWaitTimeInSeconds)
{
    string state = string.Empty;
    bool jQueryActive = true;
    try
    {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(TestCaseContext.Driver,
            TimeSpan.FromSeconds(maxWaitTimeInSeconds));
        //Checks every 500 ms whether predicate returns true if returns exit otherwise keep trying till it returns true
        wait.Until(d =>
        {
            try
            {
                state =
                    ((IJavaScriptExecutor) TestCaseContext.Driver).ExecuteScript(
                        @"return document.readyState").ToString();
                jQueryActive =
                    (bool)((IJavaScriptExecutor) TestCaseContext.Driver).ExecuteScript(
                        @"return jQuery.active == 0");
                WindowsWhenSteps.WhenIFocusTheCurrentBrowserWindow();
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
                //Ignore
            }
            return (state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
                    state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))  &&
                    jQueryActive;
        });
    }
    catch (TimeoutException)
    {
        //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
        if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
    catch (NullReferenceException)
    {
        //sometimes Page remains in Interactive mode and never becomes Complete, then we can still try to access the controls
        if (!state.Equals("interactive", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
    catch (WebDriverException)
    {
        if (TestCaseContext.Driver.WindowHandles.Count == 1)
        {
            TestCaseContext.Driver.SwitchTo().Window(TestCaseContext.Driver.WindowHandles[0]);
        }
        state =
            ((IJavaScriptExecutor) TestCaseContext.Driver).ExecuteScript(
                @"return document.readyState").ToString();
        if (
            !(state.Equals("complete", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) ||
              state.Equals("loaded", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            Assert.IsTrue(false);
    }
}
```

***NOTE:*** You can lose some of the exception handling if it seems like an overhead, but I'm aiming at full answer in favor of the future readers too.

Answer (score -1):

use the following code to check whether selenium is trigerred

```
/* * Created by SharpDevelop. 
   * User: sravanth 
   * Date: 2/2/2018 
   * Time: 1:33 AM * 
   * To change this template use Tools | Options | Coding | Edit Standard Headers. 
*/ 

using System; 
using OpenQA.Selenium; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE; 
using OpenQA.Selenium.Support.UI; 
using System.Diagnostics; 
using Microsoft.VisualBasic; 
using System.Windows.Forms; 
using System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
//using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic; 

namespace sele 
{ 
    class Program 
    { 
        public static void Main(string[] args) 
        { 
            //Console.WriteLine("Hello World!"); 
            // TODO: Implement Functionality Here 
            //Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . "); 
            //Console.ReadKey(true); 
            //System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Users/sravanth/Downloads/IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0/IEdriver.exe"); 
            // C:\Users\sravanth\Downloads\IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0 
            IWebDriver driver;
            // = new InternetExplorerDriver(@"C:\\Users/sravanth/Downloads/IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0"); 
            var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\Users/sravanth/Downloads/IEDriverServer_x64_3.8.0"); 
            //var service = InternetExplorerDriverService.CreateDefaultService(@"C:\\Users/sravanth/Downloads/chromedriver_win32"); 
            // properties on the service can be used to e.g. hide the command prompt 
            var options = new InternetExplorerOptions { IgnoreZoomLevel = true, InitialBrowserUrl = "file:///C:/Users/sravanth/Desktop/a.html", IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings = true }; 
            driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(service, options); 
            //driver = new ChromeDriver(@"C:\\Users/sravanth/Downloads/chromedriver_win32"); 
            //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_prompt"); 
            driver.Url="file:///C:/Users/sravanth/Desktop/a.html"; 
            //driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("file:///C:/Users/sravanth/Desktop/a.html"); 
            driver.Navigate(); 
            //IList links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("button")); 
            // Console.WriteLine(links.Count); 
            WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)); 
            //IWebElement btn = wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.Id("btn"))); 
            IWebElement btn=driver.FindElement(By.Id("btn")); 
            btn.Click(); 
            // System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000); 
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore"); 
            Console.WriteLine(processes.Length); 
            int i=0; 
            IntPtr windowHandle; 
            foreach (Process p in processes) 
            { 
                i=i+1; 
                Console.WriteLine(i); 
                windowHandle = p.MainWindowHandle; 
                Console.Write("iexplore"); 
                Console.WriteLine(windowHandle.ToString()); 
                // do something with windowHandle 
                if(i.Equals(1))
                { 
                    //Console.WriteLine("Reached If Loop"); 
                    SetForegroundWindow(windowHandle); 
                } 
            } 
            //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}"); 
            Console.WriteLine(processes.Length); 
            Process.Start("notepad.exe"); 
            var prc = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad"); 
            if (prc.Length > 0) 
            { 
                SetForegroundWindow(prc[0].MainWindowHandle); 
            } 
            //System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("%{F4}"); 
        } 

        [DllImport("user32.dll")] 
        private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd); 
    } 
}
```